# Ошибка в Виндовс 10 -2147219196

Tags: windows-10

При запуске любого фрагмента выходит ошибка, которая просто не дает мне ничего сделать. Помогите пожалуйста, в инете ничего не нашел, пришлось задать тут...скриншот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]